# how to break function array in rows?

Tags: php, arrays, database, codeigniter

I have this php function in codeigniter where it fetches the data from my database:

```
function fetch_data()
{
    $data = $this->projectionchart_model->make_query();
    $array = array();
    foreach($data as $row)
    {
        $array[] = $row;
    }
    $output = array(
        'current'  => intval($_POST["current"]),
        'rowCount'  => 10,
        'total'   => intval($this->projectionchart_model->count_all_data()),
        'rows'   => $array
    );
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

I want to use the `number_format` function to some of columns and right now it's building everything in an array. How could I remove the array and list the data individually as variables so I can apply a function to some of them and then output them?

Thank you

**Edit: explaining in more detail**

This function fetch_data() calls the make_query() function stored in the projectionchart_model file which contains the following:

```
function make_query()
{
 if(isset($_POST["rowCount"]))
 {
 $this->records_per_page = $_POST["rowCount"];
 }
 else
 {
  $this->records_per_page = 10;
  }
  if(isset($_POST["current"]))
  {
   $this->current_page_number = $_POST["current"];
  }
 $this->start_from = ($this->current_page_number - 1) * $this->records_per_page;
 $this->db->select("*");
 $this->db->from("projection_chart");
 if(!empty($_POST["searchPhrase"]))
 {
  $this->db->like('ae', $_POST["searchPhrase"]);
  $this->db->or_like('client', $_POST["searchPhrase"]);
  $this->db->or_like('product', $_POST["searchPhrase"]);
  $this->db->or_like('week_of', $_POST["searchPhrase"]);
  $this->db->or_like('month', $_POST["searchPhrase"]);
  $this->db->or_like('type', $_POST["searchPhrase"]);
  }
 if(isset($_POST["sort"]) && is_array($_POST["sort"]))
 {
  foreach($_POST["sort"] as $key => $value)
  {
  $this->db->order_by($key, $value);
  }
 }
 else
 {
  $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
 }
 if($this->records_per_page != -1)
 {
  $this->db->limit($this->records_per_page, $this->start_from);
  }
 $query = $this->db->get();
 return $query->result_array();
 }
```

So the output currently is this: [image]

I want to format the Planned Spend, Cleared and Total Commission with the number_format php function but right now it's all in an array.

How could I accomplish this?

Comment: use variable declaration? o.O not sure what you're really asking here...

Comment: @treyBake like $row['data'];?

Comment: Something like `$row['data'] = number_format($row['data'],2);`

Comment: To clarify your question and make it more answerable, can you show a brief example of the output that function currently produces, an example of the output you want it to produce instead, and an explanation of the changes?

Comment: @Don'tPanic I just updated the post to explain what I tried to say

Comment: @treyBake I just updated the post to explain the problem better